# Bit by Bit concatenation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a C code in which I a few variables of type SFR [R/W 1.8]. Now even I dont know what this type is. But I know that this stores a bit.
So suppose there are variables:
    A = 1
    B = 0
    C = 1
    D = 0

Now I want to concatenate them to turn them into an integer.

D C B A = 0 1 0 1 =  5

I want something like this. How can this be achieved in C?

Thank you

Comment: What's  SFR [R/W 1.8] ?

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped me figure it out. However, I didn't understand why you voted down the question? You guys should not misuse your power to vote down a question.

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but I can see why some people may have. You've not explained everything in the question (eg what SFR [R/W 1.8] means) and you've not shown what you've attempted to do so far.

Answer (score 4):

You can use bit shifting. So either something like this:

```
int answer = 0;
answer = D;
answer = (answer << 1) | C;
answer = (answer << 1) | B;
answer = (answer << 1) | A;
```

or:

```
int answer = (D << 3) | (C << 2) | (B << 1) | A;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you exactly mean, but maybe you want this.

```
unsigned A = 1, B = 0, C = 1, D = 0;
unsigned result = 0;

result |= D;
result <<= 1;
result |= C;
result <<= 1;
result |= B;
result <<= 1;
result |= A;
```

[(live example)](http://ideone.com/4BsNF2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`(D << 3) | (C << 2) | (B << 1) | A`

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know what kind of data type "SFR", so bit-operation may not work on this data type. Furthermore, you may need SFR's method that can compare to zero. (overloading or something).

```
unsigned answer = 0;
SFR zero = 0;
if (D != zero) {
    answer |= 1;
}
answer <<= 1;
if (C != zero) {
    answer |= 1;
}
answer <<= 1;
if (B != zero) {
    answer |= 1;
}
answer <<= 1;
if (A != zero) {
    answer |= 1;
}
```